# iOS 10 - QLPreviewController shows grey screen?

Tags: ios, swift3

I have sometimes the problem that the QLPreviewController shows a blank grey screen.

[image]

The file exists in the filesystem (Simulator) (and i can it normally open with Acrobat Reader from the filesystem)

Ill only use:

```
func numberOfPreviewItems(in controller: QLPreviewController) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func documentsDirectoryURL() -> URL {
    let manager = FileManager.default
    let URLs = manager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    return URLs[0]
}

func previewController(_ controller: QLPreviewController, previewItemAt index: Int) -> QLPreviewItem {
    let filepath = "bericht_\(self.task.remoteID!).pdf"

    print(filepath)
    print(documentsDirectoryURL().appendingPathComponent(filepath)) // FILEPATH CORRECT, file is there

    return documentsDirectoryURL().appendingPathComponent(filepath) as QLPreviewItem
}
```

Same code works with other files without any problems. Any ideas?

**Edit:** Ill deleted the file now manually, and let iOS create it again.

First time: QLPreviewController shows PDF
Second time: Stays grey.

Other files work well.

Comment: Have you find any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass you QLPreviewController, and see…

```
import QuickLook

class MyPreviewController: QLPreviewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // Set navigation item nil
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = nil
    }

}
```

Comment: And see what? The Controller is here, the file is here, the delegate method is getting called. So why subclassing?

Comment: Because some properties are not allowed set using instance objects. They are set at compile time (when your class is loaded). Try this and see, whether you get solution or not.